# Xcode shows error when add app groups container to apple id

Tags: ios, widget, today-extension

I am developing an app with a today extension. When I want to share the NSUserDefault data with widget, I went to set the app groups and it just showed that it failed to add app groups container to apple ID. I am using a free develop ID and the Xcode version is 7.3. Anyone knows how to fix this?? Quite annoying...Thank you sooooo much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be a part of the Apple Developer Program in order to make use of App Groups...

Comment: thx...So did I guess...Given up already and applying for a paid account...

Comment: @Alexandmrwh It's not a dead end. You can still create a widget, you just won't be able to share data between your extension and containing app.

Comment: Yeah I know this, but unfortunately my widget heavily depends on its containing app. Still thanks so much. This is my first time to ask a question here. Happy to get an answer after 6ds:)